# Importing c/pubsub module in lwc throws error in deployment

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to import `c/pubsub` module in my lwc component but it throws the following error while deploying it in org:

> **No MODULE named markup://c:pubsub found: [markup://c:caseComp] LightningComponentBundle [1,1]**

js file Code:

```js
    import { LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
    import { unregisterAllListeners } from 'c/pubsub';

    export default class caseComp extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId ;

        @track showStartBtn = true;
        @track timeVal = '0:0:0';
        timeIntervalInstance;
        totalMilliseconds = 0;

        start() {
            this.showStartBtn = false;
            let parentThis = this;

            // Run timer code in every 100 milliseconds
            this.timeIntervalInstance = setInterval(function () {

                // Time calculations for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds
                var hours = Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                //var milliseconds = Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000)));

                // Output the result in the timeVal variable
                //parentThis.timeVal = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds;
                parentThis.timeVal = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

                parentThis.totalMilliseconds += 100;
            }, 100);
        }

        stop() {
            this.showStartBtn = true;
            clearInterval(this.timeIntervalInstance);
        }

        reset() {
            this.showStartBtn = true;
            this.timeVal = '0:0:0';
            this.totalMilliseconds = 0;
            clearInterval(this.timeIntervalInstance);
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            // subscribe to event
            //this.start();
        }

        disconnectedCallback() {
            // unsubscribe from event
            unregisterAllListeners(this);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is your pubsub component? Do you have it in the project ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I followed this page - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom

Haven't done anything else (to import in project).Isn't a standard module and can be imported by line no-2 in code

Comment: You will need to have a pubsub component from that trailhead reciepe link .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce does not provide pubsub module yet out of box. So you will have to create the pubsub lwc component in your project and deploy it along .

The pubsub component can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/pubsub/pubsub.js)